# AngularJS: Using multi modules and communicating between modules?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angularjs-module

I am trying to find some  good tutorials or documents explaining AngularJS and multi modules. From what I understand its a good idea to separate angular into modules instead of using 1 module as per most of the tutorials and demos out there.

What helps me decide what to separate into modules. Take a standard web page that contains a toolbar, some functionality to deal with food (adding, updating and deleting - standard CRUD) and another functionality that deals with drinks. So from what I understand I can separate these 2 types of funcionality but what about the toolbar, this is probably soemthing that is common to both functionality so I should separate this out ?

Have things separated out into modules, how should i inject this information into my index.js ? Using angular "Include" ?

And finally communication betweem different modules, is there a standard way of doing this?

I think I have all the background of the possibilites that are available but I just can't find any concrete tutorials, documentation or examples.

I was hoping that somebody has something and they can point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is always good to separate into multiple modules, which are responsible for different sub-systems or features of the application. In Angular, the standard way is to use [`module dependency`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module) to specify that `Module Two wants to use the services/factory/provider from Module One`:

```
// Define `ModuleOne` in some JS file, say `one.js`.
angular.module('ModuleOne', [])
.factory('firstFactory', function () {
    return {
    //...
    };
});

// Use it from some other JS file, say `two.js`.
angular.module('ModuleTwo', ['ModuleOne'])
.controller('MyCtrl', ['firstFactory', function (firstFactory) {
}]);
```